# Karma + PhantomJS TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating scope.jackpot)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am still very new to unit testing, and to be honest, there isn't anything that I could even think of testing, but I cannot build my app unless I have at least 1 test case, so I attempted to make the most simple test case I could, on the smallest block of code in the controller, and it doesn't seem to be working.

I believe it's an error in my test case, and not in my controller's code itself, because when I view my app in the browser with `grunt serve` the console shows no errors.

This is the error it gives me:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of jackpot to the scope FAILED
/home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3746:53
forEach@[native code]
forEach@/home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:18
loadModules@/home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3711:12
createInjector@/home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3651:22
workFn@/home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2138:60
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.jackpot') in /home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/test/spec/controllers/main.js (line 20)
/home/elli0t/Documents/Yeoman Projects/monopoly/test/spec/controllers/main.js:20:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.04 secs / 0.007 secs)
```

This is my test case:

```
  it('should attach a list of jackpot to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.jackpot.length).toBe(2);
  });
```

And this is the block of code I'm attempting to run the test on:

```
var countInJackpot = localStorageService.get('jackpot');
$scope.jackpot = countInJackpot || [
  {
    letter: '$',
    prize: '$1,000,000 Cash',
    numbers: ['$611A','$612B','$613C','$614D','$615E','$616F','$617G','$618F'],
    count: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  },
  {
    letter: '?',
    prize: '$500,000 Vacation Home',
    numbers: ['?619A','?620B','?621C','?622D','?632E','?624F','?625G','?626H'],
    count: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  }
];
```

For the time being, I really just want to write 1 simple test case, so it will let me build the app. I'm currently studying unit testing, but I still don't feel ready to write more complex test cases on my own. I will save that for later.

I have included the entire contents of the files in a gist for reference, if needed, and I can include the contents of the karma.conf.js if necessary.

[My gist](https://gist.github.com/Etregoning/b59c15248b3264323933044dbdf743eb)

Comment: How is `scope` defined in your test? Seems that is where the problem is

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the gist link in my original post, but I have added it in now, and I'll post it in this comment too. I would post the code itself in the comment, but it seems it ignores indenting in comments, and makes anything more than 1 line harder to read. [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/Etregoning/b59c15248b3264323933044dbdf743eb)

It's the file at the bottom under the main controller

Comment: StackOverflow code formatting requires a 4-space left indent.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you'd want to test both cases of the `localStorageService` having and not having data. To do so, create a spy for `localStorageService` (see [Spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)) and write your tests like this...

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

var scope, localStorageService, localData;

beforeEach(function() {
    localData = {};

    module('monopolyApp');

    localStorageService = jasmine.createSpyObj('localStorageService', ['get', 'set']);
    localStorageService.get.and.callFake(function(key) {
        return localData[key];
    });

    inject(function($rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
});

it('assigns jackpots from local storage if present', inject(function($controller) {
    localData.jackpot = 'whatever, does not matter';

    $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        localStorageService: localStorageService
    });

    expect(localStorageService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('jackpot');
    expect(scope.jackpot).toBe(localData.jackpot);
}));

it('assigns jackpots from default array if none present in local storage', inject(function($controller) {
    $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        localStorageService: localStorageService
    });

    expect(localStorageService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('jackpot');
    expect(scope.jackpot.length).toEqual(2);

    // maybe include some other checks like
    expect(scope.jackpot[0].letter).toEqual('$');
    expect(scope.jackpot[1].letter).toEqual('?');
}));

});
```

Comment: Would this be the entire script file, instead of what I'm already using? I noticed you didn't include MainCtrl as a variable, is it not necessary? I'm sorry, I'm extremely new to unit testing so I'm still trying to make sense of all this. Thank you for the in depth example though, I will be trying it out as soon as I make sense of what everything does.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning It is now; I had initially excluded the `describe` wrapper but I've added it in now. I didn't assign the controller to a variable because there was no point, it's not used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to just copy/paste it, I'd rather write it all out by hand using your post as a reference, because it will stick in my mind better, I just didn't  want to clear out my script to write your version in and end up leaving things out. I am trying this now and will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @ElliotTregoning that's good. I wasn't intending on it being something for you to copy / paste. If you have any questions, just ask

Comment: Both tests are failing. This time it's a bit over my head and I don't even understand what the error messages from the console are trying tell me. I have included the errors in a gist, as well as my test script below it, since it's possible I messed something up since I didn't copy/paste....do you understand what's going wrong here? [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Etregoning/b7d51f3ec6f59a0ec91cf294ff630b63).

Sorry, I'm still a bit new to this unit testing thing, and I'm still struggling to understand how the code you posted works.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning yeah, those errors aren't particularly helpful. Is Karma actually loading your non-test files, ie the files where the `monopolyApp` module and `MainCtrl` controller are defined?

Comment: I would think so, you are talking about the files block in the karma.conf.js, right? I have added that file to the above Gist just incase, but from what I can tell, I have all of the necessary files included in there.

Answer (score 1):

Within your test case, scope should be $scope?

OR

You probably haven't setup your testing environment to load in your controller.

Here is an example of mine on testing a controller... Angular makes the setup a little iffy to learn, But once you understand the flow. It's pretty great :)

I'm going to try and add as many comments to explain each piece as I can... but let me know if your need clarification. You might be using jasmine, but keep in mind, this is mocha, im using the angular mock library loaded in via the karma.conf.

```
describe('myController', function() {
  var $scope,
    createController;

  // Runs before each test. Re-extantiating the controller we want to test.
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

    // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    createController = function() {
      // Creates the controller instance of our controller.
      //    We are injecting $scope so we will have access to it
      //    after the controllers code runs
      return $controller('myCtrl', {
        '$scope': $scope
      });
    };
  }));

  describe('#myFunction', function() {
    it('jackpot should contain two objects', function() {
      expect($scope.jackpot.length).to.equal(2);
    });
  });
});
```

Hope that helped. Here's some of the resources I used to learn :) Good Luck!

- https://quickleft.com/blog/angularjs-unit-testing-for-real-though/
- http://jaketrent.com/post/run-single-mocha-test/

Comment: Yes, I am using Jasmine. I am using the same methods I used for the Yeoman tutorial which covered the very basics of unit testing, and defining the scope in this way without the $ seemed to work fine for the simple todo app in the tutorial, but isn't working with the app I made. Thanks for the resources, I will definitely check them out! You have done a great job in describing how it's done, but I'm still a bit confused on the syntax for unit testing.....possibly because it's in mocha and I've been using Jasmine until now, but thanks for the info!